# How to destroy label of one class on another class in tkinter?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, label, destroy

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
master.title("Add Questions")
master.geometry("800x600")
master.geometry("+275+70")
master.configure(bg="#D3D3D3")


class timer:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.text = ""
        self.second=10
        self.l = Label(root,font=("Calibri (Body)",30),bg="#D3D3D3",fg="#333300")
        self.l.place(relx=0.9,rely=0.05,anchor=CENTER)

    def update(self):
        if self.second>0:
            m,s=divmod(self.second,60)
            self.text=str(m).zfill(2)+":"+str(s).zfill(2)
            self.l.configure(text=self.text)
            self.second=self.second-1
            self.l.after(1000,self.update)
        else:
            self.l.configure(text="Time off!",fg="red",font=("Calibri (Body)",70))
            self.l.place_configure(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)
            self.l.after(1000,lambda: questions(master))


class questions:
    def __init__(self,root):

a=timer(master)
a.update()

master.mainloop()
```

This is my code... class timer:  is for countdown. In  class questions:  I want to destroy  `self.l` label of  class timer:. But I don't know how to use `self.l` attribute in `class questions`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.destroy()` method.

This makes any widget disappear, and you can't use it again.

So, in your example, this would be `self.l.destroy()`.

As for your class, you can have the second class inherit the first class.

To do that, update your `class` like this:

`class questions(timer):`.

And this would be your timer class:

`class timer(Object):`.

Read up on [class inheritance in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp).

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: The second class shouldn't inherit from the first unless it truly is a specialization of the first. `questions` shouldn't inherit from `timer` unless `questions` _is a_ `timer`.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't aware of that. I am new to classes, so sorry.